# Get marginal values (dual) for constraints in Pyomo MIP

Tags: pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I want to access dual variables for a MIP problem developed in python with Pyomo. To my understanding the dual is not created for MIP problems, but in my opinion there should be a work around for this.

[This](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/examples/mip1_py.html) should be possible to use as a minimal working example, I'm using Gurobi myself.

I can see two possible solutions to this; 1. Fixing the binary/integer variables and resolve as LP and recreate the dual. 2. Getting dual only for the necessary constraints.

I've not been able to figure out a way to try the second method, for the first I've done something like:

```
m.solve()                      #solves the MIP problem
m.instance.x.fix()             #fixing the binary variables (only have one in actual model)
m.instance.y.fix()
m.instance.z.fix()
m.instance.preprocess()   
m.instance.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT) 
m.solve()                      #hopefully solving LP problem with dual
```

Let me know if anything is unclear or more information is needed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This method works as shown. My problem was that I had set initial values for my binary variables that were defined as 'Param(within=Binary)'. Changing the param to being 'within =[0,1]' solved my problem.